# Visualforce Page Force.com Site - Language Translation By Clicking on a "Change lang Button"

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites

I have a force.com site which I would like to translate the fields name of a form when a button was clicked.

What I did so far:

- I created a basic form
- I activated the Spanish translation and
  translated the custom fields label
- I used {!$ObjectType.Payment__c.fields.Email__c.label} to displau the label value of my field.
- I used the apex:page param : language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}

  ```
  <apex:form styleClass="form-horizontal" id="formId" >
      <h5>
          // some picklist with supported langs is required
      </h5>
      <label id="EmailId" class="control-label right-side" for="Email">{!$ObjectType.Payment__c.fields.Email__c.label}</label>
      <apex:input  html-placeholder="Please Enter Email"  styleClass="form-control" value="{!email}" />
  </apex:form>
  ```

Because the Url is a site that opens for everyone - I don't want to use the lang based on the logged in user because I don't have one.

I tried to use a javascript function where : window.location.search = 'lang=es';
Which is actually worked from developer console in chrome- but from visual force page its do nothing.

What I do want - Is to have a picklist or a button which I could choose the lang that I want to see the form.

If I adding manually to the URL : siteUrl**?lang=se** then it works.
But I want to know how can I change or add this param on the URL - from the controller or from Javascript.

Comment: try PageReference in apex: 
`return new PageReference('/siteurl?lang=se');`

Comment: for JavaScript one you check this question [Replace the parameter in URL & refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538760/replace-the-parameter-in-url-refresh-the-page).

Comment: Hey @Mahmood the second link helped a bit - but this solution does not support Internet Explorer browser and this is a little problem for my users...
The first solution does not help me in this case.
Thanks!